# How can you send mail using IMAP?

Tags: smtp, gmail, imap

I am developing a lightweight Gmail client for mobile phones, accessing Gmail by IMAP. I want to send a draft from the Drafts folder, but it has some attachments and I cannot download all of them to send it by SMTP.

Moving/copying it to "Sent Mail" does not send it, just moves it to that folder.

How can I send a Draft directly without fetching all the content and attachments from the client? Is there any IMAP command to do it?

Comment: There is an draft from one of the [Trojita](http://trojita.flaska.net/) authors providing this functionality: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kundrat-imap-submit-02

Answer (score 52, accepted):

IMAP is a mailbox protocol.  It does not (natively) support sending mail, only accessing it.  In order to send mail you *must* use SMTP.  Its possible that there is an IMAP extension for sending mail, and its possible that Google Mail supports that extension, but I doubt it.  Hence, if you want to send an email with attachments, you must actually have the full content of the message available to you to send.

Comment: In fact Google Mail doesn't support that "extension". That's why I tried to move the mail to "Sent Mail" box directly.

Answer (score 17):

IMAP was designed to receive email messages, not to send it. There is no IMAP command for sending email AFAIK. There is, however, at least one IMAP server which supports a special 'Outbox' folder. When you place the message into this folder it will be sent automatically.

Check [Courier-IMAP documentation on Sending mail via an IMAP connection](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/INSTALL.html#imapsend). Note, that this is a non standard method and I'm not aware of any other server which supports this.

There [RFC 4468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4468) which extends SMTP so it can fetch the mail content from the IMAP server, but I don't know about any working and widely used implementation.

Talking about gmail: sticking with SMTP is probably the safest way to go.

Comment: I'd love to know why this is; is it purely historical that a separate connection is used for receiving and sending? Is it because POP used to be the standard?

Comment: It's mainly just because SMTP was already well established so no need to duplicate its purpose by building email submission support into another protocol designed for a different purpose.  There's no harm in using different protocols for submission and reading - they're two very different tasks when it comes to email.

Comment: Are you not sending the message twice: once to SMPT for delivery and once to IMAP for storage. This would be inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

By the way, now that any modern mail client (including the webbased ones) supports a *Sent* folder, you typicaly have to use both SMTP and IMAP to send a single mail. And there's a race condition between sending the e-mail over SMTP and *successfully* saving the e-mail to the IMAP *Sent* folder. Using IMAP for sending e-mail is a way to avoid this race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Sending email is a special feature of some imap servers. Its nothing in the imap protocol. You just copy your email into a special imap directory on the server and it sends them. I doubt that gmail supports this.

Comment: What server(s) support this? I've never heard of this, and would like to investigate it some more.

Thanks!

Comment: Only a few years late ... Apparently [Courier Mail Server](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/INSTALL.html#imapsend) supports this.

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to my own email address using IMAP using Python 3 to a gmail account. What is does is append a message to a mailbox. You need to utilize a handful of Python's native libraries. Also study this [documentation for imaplib](http://Uploading%20Messages%C2%B6%20%20To%20add%20a%20new%20message%20to%20a%20mailbox,%20construct%20a%20Message%20instance%20and%20pass%20it%20to%20the%20append()%20method,%20along%20with%20the%20timestamp%20for%20the%20message.), this code is featured in the section **Uploading Messages:** To add a new message to a mailbox, construct a Message instance and pass it to the append() method, along with the timestamp for the message.

Then check your gmail inbox and you'll see the new message.

```
import imaplib
import time
import email.message
import imaplib_connect

new_message = email.message.Message()
new_message.set_unixfrom('name')
new_message['Subject'] = 'Test'
new_message['From'] = 'name@gmail.com'
new_message['To'] = 'name@gmail.com'
new_message.set_payload('This is an example message body.\n')

print(new_message)

with imaplib_connect.open_connection() as c:
    c.append('INBOX', '',
             imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()),
             str(new_message).encode('utf-8'))

# Show the headers for all messages in the mailbox
c.select('INBOX')
typ, [msg_ids] = c.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in msg_ids.split():
    typ, msg_data = c.fetch(num, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')
    for response_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            print('\n{}:'.format(num))
            print(response_part[1])
```

Comment: You do not "send" an email - you actually append an email in your 'Inbox' mailbox, to appear as you have received it.  That's not what OP asked for.

Comment: The `encode('utf-8')` part finally got this to work for me.