# Orbeon - Email Properties Settings

Tags: orbeon

I want to send an email to be sent from my Orbeon Form application to a host that is not gmail, following are the properties I added to my properties-local.xml

```
`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.host.MonashHealth.*"   value="remote.elodigital.com.au"/>
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.from.MonashHealth.*"   value="orbeon@elodigital.com.au"/>
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.to.MonashHealth.*"   value="nilpath899@gmail.com,orbeon@elodigital.com.au"/>
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.username.MonashHealth.*"    value="orbeon"/>
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.credentials.MonashHealth.*" value="******"/>
 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.encryption.MonashHealth.*"  value="ssl"/>
 <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.email.smtp.port.MonashHealth.*"  value="25"/>`
```

but I get the following error

```
`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection class com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection`
```

Are there any addtional properties that I must set? Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you are requiring SSL but your server on port 25 might respond with plain text. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception) for a similar error.

Comment: Thank You for replying, Could I please know if there is any way to add additional email properties other than the one's pre-defined by Orbeon? For example protocol, socket factory class, socket factory fall back...etc

Comment: I think all the properties are documented. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/EmailProcessor.scala) to see how it actually works if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Could I please know, if this works with imaps protocol as well? Suppose I can not use smtp, is there a way I could configure to set the protocol to imaps?

Comment: Sending email uses SMTP not IMAP. See also this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627596/how-can-you-send-mail-using-imap).

Comment: Thank you so much, changed the mail server configurations to use SMTP and it worked.