# sending mail via IMAP through action-mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail-imap, imaplib

i am already  implemented send mail through smtp protocol
now i trying to implement via IMAP..protocol....what should i have to change in 
config/devlopment .rb

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 9292}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:        'imap.gmail.com'or'imap.hotmail.com'or'imap.yahoo.com', #      default: localhost
     port:           '25',                  # default: 25
    user_name:      'debasish.industrify2016@gmail.com',
  password:       'debxxxxxxxx',
    authentication: :plain                 # :plain, :login or :cram_md5
 }
```

Comment: IMAP is for accessing an email mailbox, not delivering new mail. Only SMTP or some equivalent API wrapper around SMTP can do that.

Comment: actually i develop a system that work as outlook.like user login on the system for the first time and accessing all time...like our moble app...what can i do in web

Comment: SMTP is for delivery. IMAP is for fetching *already delivered* emails. They're two different things. See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627596/how-can-you-send-mail-using-imap).